# Tag correction: [politcal-correctness]

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

The [politcal-correctness](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/politcal-correctness) tag is misspelled. Could someone please correct it. (There are currently only two questions with this tag.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually go ahead and edit the tags and someone else with sufficient rep (currently 15 of them) will approve your edits.